# ¿Cómo concatenar un atributo en el src de un iFrame?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net

Estoy intentando mostrar un video sacado de YouTube en un `iframe` con `ASP.net` . El URL lo guardo en una base de datos en `SQL Server` y en `Visual Studio` en un atributo que es el que quiero que se concatene.

`<iframe id = 'iFrameVideo' width ="640" height="480">  ></iframe>`

Y en el codebehind tengo esto:

`iFrameVideo.Src = objA.urlVideo;`

Cualquier cosa si la pregunta está incompleta solo díganme y posteo más del código.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No puedes utilizar el `iframe` porque pertenece al código de cliente y estás intentando acceder desde código de servidor. Si quieres utilizarlo desde el servidor, debes indicarle que deseas acceder utilizando el atributo `runat`:

```
 <iframe id='iFrameVideo' runat="server" ....></iframe>
```

Otra forma de hacerlo es utilizar un control de servidor como `asp:Literal` y en la propiedad `Text` insertar la cadena HTML.

Si quieres hacerlo así, en tu código aspx debes escribir algo similar a esto:

```
 <asp:Literal id='ltrFrame' runat='server' />
```

y en tu código CSharp (behind-code):

```
 ltrFrame.Text = @"<iframe id='iFrameVideo' width='640' height='480' 
                            src='" + objA.urlVideo + '></iframe>"
```

Comment: Hola y gracias por contestar en las 2 preguntas, por ahora no puedo probar esto que me decís ya que no tengo pc pero por lo que veo en el código que pusiste es eso mismo lo que estaba buscando, saludos.